# Light nodes dont work with the Ethereum blockchain after the Merge any alternatives

Tags: ethereum, nodes, web3js

So I was trying to deploy a light node and looked into this tutorial
https://ethereum.org/en/developers/tutorials/run-light-node-geth/

It say that light nodes dont work right now with the Ethereum blockchain after the Merge.

I want to fetch transactions from web3 using a light node. I dont have the requirement to run a full node currently. Is there any alternative to that? (without using something like infura)